# How to make the triangle to move around just like the circle and rectangle shapes?

Tags: c#, winforms

The code in the paint event:

```
private void pictureBoxCroppedImages_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (drawBorder)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, pictureBoxCroppedImages.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }

    if (!isRealTimeCropping)
    {
        if (rectImage != null && DrawingRects.Count > 0)
        {
            var dr = DrawingRects.Last();
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(rectImage, dr.Rect);

            if (clearRectangles)
            {
                DrawingRects.Clear();
                pictureBoxImageToCrop.Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    if (isRealTimeCropping && realTimeCroppedImage != null)
    {
        // Handle cropping shape based on radio button selection
        if (radioButtonCircular.Checked)
        {
            using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                path.AddEllipse(realTimeCursorPos.X, realTimeCursorPos.Y, realTimeCroppedImage.Width, realTimeCroppedImage.Height);
                e.Graphics.SetClip(path);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(realTimeCroppedImage, realTimeCursorPos);
            }
        }

        if (radioButtonRectangular.Checked)
        {
            using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                path.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(realTimeCursorPos.X, realTimeCursorPos.Y, realTimeCroppedImage.Width, realTimeCroppedImage.Height));
                e.Graphics.SetClip(path);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(realTimeCroppedImage, realTimeCursorPos);
            }
        }

        if(radioButtonTriangle.Checked)
        {
            using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                // Define the points of the triangle based on realTimeCursorPos
                // These points will form a triangle centered at realTimeCursorPos
                Point[] trianglePoints =
                {
    new Point(realTimeCursorPos.X, realTimeCursorPos.Y - realTimeCroppedImage.Height / 2), // Top point
    new Point(realTimeCursorPos.X - realTimeCroppedImage.Width / 2, realTimeCursorPos.Y + realTimeCroppedImage.Height / 2), // Bottom-left point
    new Point(realTimeCursorPos.X + realTimeCroppedImage.Width / 2, realTimeCursorPos.Y + realTimeCroppedImage.Height / 2)  // Bottom-right point
};

                // Add the triangle to the path
                path.AddPolygon(trianglePoints);

                // Set the clip region for drawing
                e.Graphics.SetClip(path);

                // Draw the real-time cropped image centered at realTimeCursorPos
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(realTimeCroppedImage,
                                      realTimeCursorPos.X - realTimeCroppedImage.Width / 2,
                                      realTimeCursorPos.Y - realTimeCroppedImage.Height / 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is a problem with the triangle part.  my guess but I'm not sure is something with the Y size of the triangle.

anyway, when I change the size of the triangle to 100 it's working fine the triangle is moving around.  but if for example i change the triangle size to 500 the triangle stay in the same position the cropped image is moving inside the triangle and the triangle change his shape each time i move the mouse.

not like in the circle and the rectangle if I'm changing the size of them to 500, they keep moving fine.

i also tried to use first offsets for the triangle but it didn't help much for the problem:

```
if(radioButtonTriangle.Checked)
{
    using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
    {
        int offsetX = realTimeCursorPos.X;
        int offsetY = realTimeCursorPos.Y;
        
        // Handle bounds for X and Y
        if (offsetX + realTimeCroppedImage.Width / 2 > pictureBoxImageToCrop.Width)
        {
            offsetX = pictureBoxImageToCrop.Width - realTimeCroppedImage.Width / 2;
        }

        if (offsetX - realTimeCroppedImage.Width / 2 < 0)
        {
            offsetX = realTimeCroppedImage.Width / 2;
        }

        if (offsetY + realTimeCroppedImage.Height / 2 > pictureBoxImageToCrop.Height)
        {
            offsetY = pictureBoxImageToCrop.Height - realTimeCroppedImage.Height / 2;
        }

        if (offsetY - realTimeCroppedImage.Height / 2 < 0)
        {
            offsetY = realTimeCroppedImage.Height / 2;
        }

        // Define points to create triangle shape
        Point point1 = new Point(offsetX - realTimeCroppedImage.Width / 2, offsetY + realTimeCroppedImage.Height / 2);
        Point point2 = new Point(offsetX + realTimeCroppedImage.Width / 2, offsetY + realTimeCroppedImage.Height / 2);
        Point point3 = new Point(offsetX, offsetY - realTimeCroppedImage.Height / 2);
        Point[] points = new Point[] { point1, point2, point3 };

        path.AddPolygon(points);
        e.Graphics.SetClip(path);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(realTimeCroppedImage, offsetX - realTimeCroppedImage.Width / 2, offsetY - realTimeCroppedImage.Height / 2);
    }
}
```

very small video clip showing how it's working fine with the circle and rectangle but not with the triangle:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaCLBGXEVQI

Comment: Why at the end of the clip did the picture mode. The woman is in the upper left of the background instead of being centered?  How are you calculating the offset?

Comment: @jdweng now I'm not calculating the offset i tried to calculate it in the second example in my question body.  using offsetX and offsetY but it didn't work either.  i know the woman is in the upper left corner but not sure why.  that's the problem.  the triangle is not moving around when the size is 500 or even less like 350 or 400.

Comment: It looks like when you use rectangle you are creating a new rectangle : path.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(realTimeCursorPos.X, realTimeCursorPos.Y, realTimeCroppedImage.Width, realTimeCroppedImage.Height));  Are you doing equivalent for a triangle?

Comment: [How to drag and move shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38749134/3110834)